# Cleaning outliers inside a column with interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, signal-processing

I'm trying to do the following.
I have some data with wrong values (`x<=0` or `x>=1100`) inside a dataframe.
I am trying to change those values to values inside an acceptable range.

For the time being, this is what I do code-wise

```
def while_non_nan(A, k):
    init = k
    if k+1 >= len(A)-1:
        return A.iloc[k-1]
    while np.isnan(A[k+1]):
        k += 1
    #Calculate the value.
    n = k-init+1
    value = (n*A.iloc[init-1] + A.iloc[k])/(n+1)
    return value

evoli.loc[evoli['T1'] >= 1100, 'T1'] = np.nan
evoli.loc[evoli['T1'] <= 0, 'T1'] = np.nan
inds = np.where(np.isnan(evoli))
#Place column means in the indices. Align the arrays using take
for k in inds[0] :
    evoli['T1'].iloc[k] =  while_non_nan(evoli['T1'], k)
```

I transform the outlier values into nan.
Afterwards, I get the position of those nan.
Finally, I modify the nan to the mean value between the previous value and the next one.
Since, several nan can be next to each other, the `whie_non_nan` search for the next non_nan value and get the ponderated mean.

Example of what I'm hoping to get:

```
Input :
[nan 0 1 2 nan 4 nan nan 7 nan ]

Output:
[0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 ]
```

Hope it is clear enough. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has a builtin interpolation you could use after setting your limits to `NaN`:

```
from numpy import NaN
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"T1": [1, 2, NaN, 3, 5, NaN, NaN, 4, NaN]})

df["T1"] = df["T1"].interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill()
print(df)
```

[Interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) is a DataFrame method that fills `NaN` values with specified interpolation method (linear in this case). Calling `.bfill()` for [backward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and `.ffill()` for [forward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) ensures the 1st and last item are also replaced if needed, with 2nd and 2nd to last item respectively. If you want some fancier strategy for 1st and last item you need to write it yourself.

Comment: Terrific ! It is exactly what I needed. If it is not tu much to ask, can you explain a bit more ? I'm do not understand why it did work :)